# User [X] does not have permission to access user [X:importSshPublicKey]

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to run `cloud compute os-login ssh-keys add`:
I get

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.os-login.ssh-keys.add) 
User [X] does not have permission to access user [X:importSshPublicKey] (or it may not exist): 
Insufficient IAM permissions. 
The instance belongs to an external organization. 
You must be granted the roles/compute.osLoginExternalUser IAM role 
on the external organization to configure POSIX account information.
```

where X is the same user in both cases. How to add the permissions I need via the `gcloud` command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Determine the current account (MEMBER) that you are using

```
gcloud auth list
```

List the Google Cloud Projects:

```
gcloud projects list
```

Use the following command. Replace PROJECT_ID with the Project ID (not project name). Replace MEMBER with the email address of the account from above.

For a service account:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding PROJECT_ID --member=serviceAccount:MEMBER --role=roles/compute.osLoginExternalUser
```

For a user account:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding PROJECT_ID --member=user:MEMBER --role=roles/compute.osLoginExternalUser
```

To modify the IAM settings on a project you need the permission `resourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy`. If you do not have this permission you will need to ask a project administrator to perform this task for you.

This permission is part of the Project IAM Admin role `roles/resourcemanager.projectIamAdmin` or Organization Administrator role  `roles/resourcemanager.organizationAdmin`

[Cloud IAM Overview](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview)

[Understanding roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles)

[gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/add-iam-policy-binding)

Comment: When doing your command, I get: `ERROR: (gcloud.projects.add-iam-policy-binding) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Policy members must be of the form "<type>:<value>".`
When using `--member=user:MEMBER` I get `ERROR: (gcloud.projects.add-iam-policy-binding) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Role roles/compute.osLoginExternalUser is not supported for this resource.`

Comment: I updated the answer. If you read the documentation you need to specify a user or serviceAccount with the MEMBER id. I am not sure if this role supports a service account for the MEMBER. You may have to use your USER ID.